# Neater presentation of a facet_grid in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm interested in trying to visualize data in ggplot, but I'm sure I'm not approaching it the correct way. I'd like to take this visualization:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, colour=Diet, group=Chick)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

and break it out into a different plot per chick. My very naive approach was to use a `facet_grid()` for each chick:

```
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight)) + facet_grid(Chick ~ .)
```

But this produces an unusable result:

[image]

The result I'm looking for would be something like `multiplot()`, but I don't want to have to build 50 different plots, then multiplot on those.

I'm sure there's a straight-forward answer that's staring me in the face, but my ggplot hacking skills aren't super finely tuned.

Comment: There are 50 different chicks. Do you think a single chart is the best way to visualize them?

Comment: Perhaps you can try `facet_wrap` and use `ncol` or `nrow` to adjust the layout. For example, replace your `facet_grid` call with `facet_wrap(~ Chick, ncol = 10)`.

Comment: Thanks ycw, that's what I was looking for. The end result of `ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight)) + facet_wrap(~ Chick, ncol = 10) + geom_line()` works great.